# JSON passed to ApiController doesn't deserialize string values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm trying to pass a JSON array to an ApiController but the string values aren't deserializing (they are set to null values). The strange thing is that I still get the correct number of elements.

A have an ApiController:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/language")]
public class LanguagePairApiController : ApiController
```

With a post method:

```
// POST: api/language/create
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
public string Create([FromBody]LanguagePair[] languagePairs)
```

I'm sending JSON to it:

```
[
    {"Key":"Test","Value":"Test","Version":"1.0"},
    {"Key":"Areyousure","Value":"Are you sure?","Version":"1.0"},
    {"Key":"File","Value":"File","Version":"1.0"}
]
```

And this is the class I'm trying to map it to:

```
public class LanguagePair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

But the string values are coming through as null:

[image]

What am I missing?
**EDIT: I've figured out one answer to this and posted it below. But I'm still looking for a better answer...**

Comment: I do not know much about asp.net, but isn't there some mechanism turned on that automatically camel cases object properties? Try to send `[{"key":"win"}]` to it.

Comment: what is your actual jQuery you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to decorate the class with DataContract and DataMember attributes:

```
{
    [DataContract]
    public class LanguagePair
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to adjust names for JSON properties (e.g. send {"myKey":"Areyousure","question event with space":"Are you sure?","v":"1.0"} ) you can use correspondingly: [DataMember(Name = "myKey")], [DataMember(Name = "question event with space")], [DataMember(Name = "v")] for the LanguagePair properties in C#

Answer (score 1):

Read [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

You need to remove `[FromBody]` attribute from your action...

```
// POST: api/language/create
[HttpPost]
[Route("create")]
public string Create(LanguagePair[] languagePairs) { ... }
```

and you can keep your class lean as you originally had it:

```
public class LanguagePair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

> **Using [FromBody]**
>
> To force Web API to **read a simple type from the request body**, add the
>   `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter:
>
> ```
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```
>
> In this example, Web API will use a media-type formatter to read the
>   value of name from the request body. Here is an example client
>   request.
>
> ```
> POST http://localhost:5076/api/values HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Fiddler
> Host: localhost:5076
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 7
>
> "Alice"
> ```
>
> When a parameter has `[FromBody]`, Web API uses the Content-Type
>   header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is
>   "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a
>   JSON object).

Comment: I just tried this and I get the same result (an array of 3 objects with all the values == null). But the [FromBody] is doing nothing - if I remove that and keep the [DataContract] it works correctly.